# getting syntax error as output after compiling lex and yaac program

Tags: bison, lex

Here is lex code for generating tokens and lexemes

```
%{
     // Lex program
    
    #include "nlp1.tab.h"

    
%}

%%
is|am|was|were      {return VERBTOKEN;}
boy|girl            {return NOUNTOKEN;}
he|she|He|She       {return PRONOUNTOKEN;}
and|or          {return CONJTOKEN;}
fine            {return ADVTOKEN;}
a|an|the        {return ARTICLETOKEN;}
good|bad             {return ADJTOKEN;} 
[.]\n               {return 0;}
quit|QUIT           {exit(0);}


%%
int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

yaac program for getting token and semantic checking

```
%{
    // yacc program

      #include<stdio.h>
    
%}

%token VERBTOKEN NOUNTOKEN PRONOUNTOKEN ADJTOKEN 
%token ADVTOKEN CONJTOKEN PREPTOKEN DEFTOKEN ARTICLETOKEN

%%
stat:    compound   {printf("\n This Is A Compound Statement.\n\n");}
    |simple {printf("\n This Is A Simple Statement.\n\n");}
    ;

compound: simple CONJTOKEN simple
    ;

simple:  subject VERBTOKEN ARTICLETOKEN object
           |subject VERBTOKEN ARTICLETOKEN ADJTOKEN object
           |subject VERBTOKEN ADVTOKEN
    ;
    
subject:     NOUNTOKEN
        |PRONOUNTOKEN
            ;
object:    NOUNTOKEN
%%

extern FILE *yyin;
int main(void)
{
    printf("\n\n Please put a dot . at the end of statement.");
    printf("\n Type quit to exit.\n\n");
    do
    {
        yyparse();
    }while(!feof(yyin));

    return 0;
}

int yyerror(char *s)
{
    printf("\n %s.\n", s);
}
```

After compiling and give the input and enter it is saying syntax error.

OUTPUT:-

> C:\Users\Rushikesh\compiler design>nlp1.exe

> Please put a dot . at the end of statement.
> Type quit to exit.

> He is a boy.

> syntax error.

> syntax error.

Comment: You cannot just call `yyparse` multiple times. Adjust your grammar to handle multiple `stat`s and call it once, without explicitly returning `0` from the lexer.